# Kubernetes scheduler policy config causes seemingly irrelevant error

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes version 1.17.4

Trying to toy around with custom scheduler priorities, I'm passing `--policy-config-file` pointing to file with following contents:

```
  kind: Policy
  apiVersion: v1
  predicates:
    - name: CheckNodeUnschedulable
    - name: GeneralPredicates
    - name: PodFitsResources
    - name: PodToleratesNodeTaints
    - name: CheckVolumeBinding
    - name: MaxEBSVolumeCount
    - name: MatchInterPodAffinity
    - name: NoDiskConflict
    - name: NoVolumeZoneConflict
    - name: MatchNodeSelector
    - name: HostName
  priorities:
    - {name: BalancedResourceAllocation, weight: 1}
    - {name: LeastRequestedPriority, weight: 1}
    - {name: ServiceSpreadingPriority, weight: 1}
    - {name: NodePreferAvoidPodsPriority, weight: 1}
    - {name: NodeAffinityPriority, weight: 1}
    - {name: TaintTolerationPriority, weight: 1}
    - {name: ImageLocalityPriority, weight: 1}
    - {name: SelectorSpreadPriority, weight: 1}
    - {name: InterPodAffinityPriority, weight: 1}
```

which, i believe, is the default set of predicates and policies, however kubernetes scheduler fails to start with following error:

```
F0417 12:35:52.291434       1 factory.go:265] error initializing the scheduling framework: plugin "NodeName" already registered as "FilterPlugin"
```

The `NodeName` is not mentioned anywhere in my config file. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I've looked in the source code for this error, and found something with plugin related... I'm checking in my lab cluster and come back asap with some information.

Comment: I've tested in my lab server and I didn't get the same behavior from your log... I've tried as file using `--policy-config-file=...` and with configMap with `--policy-configmap=...`. My cluster was installed following the guide [kubernetes-the-hard-way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) but with k8s version 1.17.4.  So how did you install your cluster? Is in production or just a lab server?

Comment: @KoopaKiller it's a staging server that is meant to replicate production configuration. setup by kubeadm. is there a way to find the reason there is some name conflict? i don't think i have anything out of the ordinary in the configs.

Comment: How many nodes there are in your cluster? I've tried in a cluster already provisioned by kubeadm changing the file  `/etc/kubernetes/manifest/kube-scheduler.yaml` and adding the parameter and didn't work! I'll try once again using a new kubeadm setup. I'll come back soon.

Comment: I can't to reproduce the same behavior... Did you test with the new Kubernetes version (1.18.2) e got the same result ?

Answer (score 1):

In this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/#options) you can see the parameter `--policy-config-file` is deprecated and the use is not recommended.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/2db6ec1db7505b092c8e50eb8f10cd3a5f9950af/pkg/scheduler/framework/plugins/default_registry.go#L115)  you can see that  `GeneralPredicates`  and  `HostName`  use the same  `nodename`  plugin:

**NodeName Predicate:**

```
registry.RegisterPredicate(predicates.GeneralPred,
...
  plugins.Filter = appendToPluginSet(plugins.Filter, nodename.Name, nil)
...
```

**Hostname predicate:**

```
registry.RegisterPredicate(predicates.HostNamePred,
...
  plugins.Filter = appendToPluginSet(plugins.Filter, nodename.Name, nil)
...
```

So you could try to disable one of them and see if the error persist.

This should solve the issue for `nodename` plugin but if an other collision was detected you could try to solve in the same way.